# Text placed at distance from line, given radius and angle

Tags: nodes

Assume a line from A to B. At p% (or p mm/cm) of the distance from A to B, starting from A, I want to "turn" using a radius r and an angle y relative to the AB direction (y=0 is in the direction of the line AB, 90=90 degrees to the left of the direction of the line AB, etc.) and place a text there.

The following command,

```
\node at ($(A)!0.5!10:(B)$){x};
```

angles the 'x' 10 degree to the horizontal plane, around A (not at the 50% distance) with the radius 50% of the distance between A and B but I like to have a more general command where I can specify the radius and angle, relative to the line direction at p% of the line distance, starting from A. Is this possible? TIA! (I'm sorry for the confusing description/question!)

Comment: This is what the last example in section **13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers** of the pgfmanual v 3.1.4 does.

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (3,1);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
  \path ($ ($ (a)!.5!(b) $)!1cm!90:(b) $) node{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` where `.5` is the fraction, `1cm` the radius and `90` the angle. You can adjust each of these as you like.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `calc` library allows you to specify the radius and angle of rotation. What do you think is not enough when using this library?

Comment: The calc library works fine, but I did not know of the nested method, described by Schrödinger's cat. I should really read the manual. My fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the last example in section **13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers of the pgfmanual v 3.1.4** does. By nesting the `calc` syntax you can combine the directives used there to one.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\coordinate (a) at (1,0); 
\coordinate (b) at (3,1); 
\draw (a) -- (b); \path ($ ($ (a)!.5!(b) $)!1cm!90:(b) $) node{x}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

If you want to use these things repeatedly, it may make sense to define a style in which the fraction, radius and angle are stored in pgf keys.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[between/.style args={#1 and #2}{/tikz/insert path={%
 ($ ($ (#1)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mf67/fraction}!(#2)
 $)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mf67/radius}!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mf67/angle}:(#2) $)}},
 mf67/.cd,fraction/.initial=.5,radius/.initial=1cm,angle/.initial=90,
 ]
  \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,1);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \path[between=A and B] node{x};
  \path[mf67/.cd,fraction=0.2,radius=1.5cm,angle=-30,/tikz/between=A and B] node{y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Schrödinger's cat is here and it's not here!